# CSS - How can I set the color of strings written using "innerHTML" into a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a function that outputs an array of strings into an html page. How can I set the color of the output text? This is the code that writes into a page:

```
function showErrors() {
    if (errList.length >= 1)
    document.getElementById("errorsSpace").innerHTML = errList.join('<br/>');
}
```

Ive tried using "color: red" with no luck. I get an error that says "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

here is a jsfiddle for the rest of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/wd6fpgm6/

Comment: The most basic way would be to add style="color:red" to the errorsSpace element

Comment: document.getElementById("errorsSpace").style.color="red";

Comment: @dmoo i currently have that in my external CSS but no visible changes and I get the error

Comment: You need this - <div id= "errorSpace" style="color:red">

Comment: @dmoo is there a difference if I did #errorSpace {color: red;} in my external CSS?

Comment: Please show how you tried to use `color: red` with no luck? If you want help fixing your code, you have to show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try these methods?

```
document.getElementById("errorsSpace").setAttribute("style", "color:red");
```

or

```
document.getElementById("errorsSpace").style.color = "red";
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following - convert the array to a string containing both the html and the error class which is styled in the CSS - then the entire string is inserted into the hhtml and has correct structure and styling:

```
//CSS
.error{color:red}

//js
function showErrors() {
    var errors ="";
    if (errList.length >= 1)
      {
        for(i=0;i<errList.length;i++){
         errors+="<p class='error'>" + errList[i] + "</p>;";
          }
        document.getElementById("errorsSpace").innerHTML = errors;
      }
}

//result will be 

<div id='errorsSpace'>
    <p class='error'>Error 1</p>;
    <p class='error'>Error 2</p>;
    <p class='error'>Error 3</p>;
</div>
```

you could even leave out the class="error" on the p and have the css be :

```
#errorsSpace p{color:red}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing an 
 tag after every error, you can place every error in a paragraph tag and just set the color of the tag.

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean "placing a tag after every error?" I place the errors into a div  that is placed above my form.

Comment: The solution I'm suggesting is what @gavgrif did.

Comment: sorry @Chrez - didn't realise you had got there first - thought I was being clever :))

Comment: @nanjero05 - i think the main difference between the way you are doing it now and the way Chrez and I are suggesting is that your way will result in a div with naked text and linebreaks but no correct markup, and our way will yield semantically correct <p> elements which will not need linebreaks because they are block level elements. Having them in p tags also allows for further CSS or JS manipulation of the content.